# Using DocuSign Integration Client C# .NET to programmatically create Template and set TemplateRoles

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the DocuSign Integrations Client .net wrapper around API. I'm trying to programmatically create a Template and set the TemplateRoles and then load the Console so user can attach their documents and set their signing tabs. However the TemplateRoles are not preset when the Template loads in the console. The user still has to select "Place Holder" and enter a RoleName.... Here is a sample of my code:

```
if (loggedIn) 
{ 
    DocuSign.Integrations.Client.Template template = new DocuSign.Integrations.Client.Template(); 

    template.Login = _account; 

    List roles = new List(); 
    TemplateRole templateRoleSubscriber = new TemplateRole(); 
        templateRoleSubscriber.roleName = "Subscriber"; 
        templateRoleSubscriber.routingOrder = "1"; 
        templateRoleSubscriber.defaultRecipient = "true"; 
    roles.Add(templateRoleSubscriber); 

    TemplateRole templateRoleApprover = new TemplateRole(); 
        templateRoleApprover.roleName = "Approver"; 
        templateRoleApprover.routingOrder = "2"; 
        templateRoleApprover.defaultRecipient = "true"; 
    roles.Add(templateRoleApprover); 

    template.TemplateRoles = roles.ToArray(); 

    if (template.CreateTemplate(new List(), new List(), "New Template")) 
    { 
        //Save Template in our database as a 'linked' document 
        Template.DocuSignTemplateId = template.EnvelopeId; 
        Template = _SignatureRepo.SaveTemplate(Template); 

       //Load DocuSign Console to finish editing template. 
       _account.GetUserConsoleView(); 
       return _account.ConsoleUrl; 
    }
}
```

So, once the console loads, I see the "New Template" that just got created. But when I edit it the Roles are not set.

Please help.... Thank you.

By the way, I'm using the full open source code set for DocuSign Integrations Client, so I'm able to step into the CreateTemplate method call and see the TemplateRoles are being added to the body of the request.

Comment: Have you tried just creating the Template through code then simply logging in to Website and the downloading the XML definition of the template you just created and verifying it?  That might yield what's wrong with it...

Comment: Just saw your response... Thank you... I've downloaded the template xml and can see that the TemplateRoles are not there. So that definitely helped me in troubleshooting.